# jQuery works in Internet Explorer but not in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: php, firefox, google-chrome

I have written the following very simple jQuery post. It works in Internet Explorer but not in either Chrome or Firefox:

```
<script>
function showphone(){
    $.post('phonedata.php',{    
        k: document.getElementById('k').value,
        s: document.getElementById('s').value
    },
    function(output){
        $('#showphone').html(output);
    }); 
}
showphone();
</script>
```

Is there anything that I can do for Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: in IE, it can successfully post something back; in Chrome and ff, it simply shows nothing...

Comment: Markup? Does IE still do that weird thing where it treats `name` attributes as `id`? Also, why alternate between gEBI and jQuery selectors? Also, why use gEBI for a form field instead of formElement.fieldName?

Comment: do you mean `phonedata.php` returns nothing or it simply cannot receive **any** output? Try adding a `echo "testing";` in your php

Comment: I observe that .post cannot call phonedata.php

Comment: Try using [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) as of [this note](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#notes-0)

Comment: I found the solution. I forgot to assign id = "k" and id = "s" to the elements. Interestingly, even without id="k", IE can capture name="k" to perform .post. Learnt a lesson :D

Comment: And I was thinking that why don't you use jQuery selectors `$("#k").val()` instead of `document.getElementById('k').value`, if you are using jQuery anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
showphone();
});
```